# elements of HashMap are in the wrong order

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to read two columns (both String) from a file and keep the values of the first column in a HashMap where the Integer is the counter.

For example if the file I am reading is

```
Apple Fruit
PC    Device
Pen   Tool
...
```

and the code is

```
    String line="";
    int counter=1;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"),"Unicode"));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] words;
        words= st.split(" ");
            tokens.put(counter, words[0]);
        counter+=1;
    }
```

The problem is when I print The HashMap values, I found the values are in different order of that in the origianl file

```
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> token:tokens.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(token.getKey() + token.getValue());
    }
```

I got the following

```
1   Apple
3   Pen
4   whatever
2   ..etc
```

I do not know what is the problem?! can you please help me with that

Comment: You will need to use a different container.  The very nature of a hashmap implementation all but guarantees that the original order will not be preserved.

Comment: What do you think the correct order is here?

Comment: depending on the key!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As the documentation clearly states, HashMaps are *unordered*.
The enumeration order is determined by the hascodes of the keys.

If you want to preserve insertion order when enumerating the map, use `LinkedHashMap`.
If you want enumeration order to follow the natural ordering of the keys, use `TreeMap`.

Comment: Ok, on which basis the elements are ordered in HashMap? why this order !!!! why 4 coming before 2

Comment: @Wahedsaw: It's based on the hashcodes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable

Comment: @Wahedsaw Order of elements is based on hashcode value of keys. Take a look [[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596549/how-does-javas-hashmap-work-internally)] for more details about HashMap.

Comment: @Wahedsaw The order you see is the the standard sorting of the hashes of the keys.

Comment: A `HashMap` stores its data in a bunch of lists called buckets.  When you add a key-value pair, the map calls `key.hashCode()`, takes it modulo the number of buckets, and puts it into that numbered bucket.  When a bucket gets too big, the map creates more buckets, and adjusts *all* of the pairs in the map. This is one reason why you can't mutate a map while you iterate over it.  As you see, the order of the buckets and the items in each bucket will change with time. Because of the modular reduction, not even the hash codes order the items.

Answer (score 6):

`HashMap` is not ordered.  You don't have any control over what order the items appear in.  If you want an ordered map, you can use, for example, `TreeMap`.

**EDIT:** thanks to those that brought this up: `TreeMap` will keep items in the natural sorting order (i.e. in your case in alphabetical order).  `LinkedHashMap` will preserve the order of insertion.

Comment: But that will use natural ordering or require a comparator. I would suggest `LinkedHashMap` for insertion order.

Comment: @PaulBellora Fair play.  That's why I said _for example_ `TreeMap`.  The OP didn't specify what order he/she is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use LinkedHashMap , if you want insertion order back. By default HashMap's iterator doesn't guarantee insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` is not an ordered `Collection`. (It is not even a `Collection`) It is more like a dictionary.

If you want to perserve the order of the items you can either use a `TreeMap` or a `LinkedHashMap`.

The difference between these is that `TreeMap` keeps them ordered by their natural sort order while `LinkedHashMap` keeps the insertion order.

In most cases where you would like to have something like with using a `List` you can use the `LinkedHashMap`.

`TreeMap` uses a red-black tree for its internal implementation while `LinkedHashMap` uses doubly linked list.

My suggestion is that you should refer to the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html). There you will find thorough explanations.

Additionally the idiomatic way to iterate over `Map`s is this:

```
for(Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    String myString = map.get(key);
    // ...
}
```